# Integrate nodeJS with codeigniter

Tags: node.js, codeigniter-2

Hi i am planning to integrate real time commenting system and chat with nodejs in codeigniter..

But how to achieve that can anybody help me out???

Thanks

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ what have you tried ?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer but go through the links provided in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) and [Socket.IO](http://Socket.IO) to get your live data at your clients browser. And also you can use this along with your [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) or [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) site.

Only important thing is how do you build your socket.io server & emit data as you need to client browser.

Happy Exploring  :-)

For more details on Node.JS Socket.IO package click [here](https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io)